# Partial type assertion to a destructured Array

Tags: typescript

I have below example code.

```
Promise.all([PromiseA, PromiseB])
          .then(([resultA, resultB]) => {}
```

I know the types of resultA and resultB. But I want to type assert only resultB.
How can I achieve

```
Promise.all([PromiseA, PromiseB])
          .then(([resultA, resultB: TypeB]) => {}
```

The syntax above is wrong. I need to specify the type for only resultB, while resultA should inherit whatever the type of resultA.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Promise.all([new Promise<number>(() => {}), new Promise<string>(() => {}) as unknown as boolean])
            .then(([resultA, resultB]) => { }
```

now `resultB` is of type `boolean`.

adapt to your needs.

```js
Promise.all([PromiseA, PromiseB as unknown as boolean])
          .then(([resultA, resultB]) => {}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the usage of as unknown as.

Comment: if you try to cast something to another type, typescript will check if that cast is OK or not. if there is no data/interface overlap between the types, an error will be thrown. Therefore you have to cast to ```unknown``` first. With unknown you tell the compiler explicitly that the type you are casting to is correct. Try removing the ```as unknown``` and see the error message :)

Comment: @capc0, isn't `as any as X` more common? Curious